# Why is mysqli_real_escape_string adding two backslashes to my string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am running php 5.5.9

I am POSTing the following text to a php script that will insert it into the field of a mysql table.

> This is becoming quite a nuisance ' and why is that

I am using the following code to assign POSTed data to a variable (plus debugging code.)

```
$ITEMDESC2 = $_POST['ITEMDESC'];
$ITEMDESC = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn1, $ITEMDESC2);

error_log("ITEMDESC: $ITEMDESC  ITEMDESC2: $ITEMDESC2");
```

The following appears in my apache log file:

> ITEMDESC: This is becoming quite a nuisance \\' and why is that
>   ITEMDESC2: This is becoming quite a nuisance ' and why is that

Why is `$ITEMDESC` being escaped with double backslashes, instead of single backslashes?

I have read that this can be caused by magic_quotes, but as I understand it, they were removed in PHP 5.4

Any insight into this would be welcome.

Edit: Adding more complete, working example as requested.

```
<?php 
$conn1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'DB') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$ITEMDESC = "This is Bob's Text";
$ITEMDESC2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn1, $ITEMDESC);
$SQL = "insert into table (description) values ('{$ITEMDESC2}');";

echo "<br>ITEMDESC: {$ITEMDESC}";
echo "<br>ITEMDESC2: {$ITEMDESC2}";
echo "<br>SQL: {$SQL}";

error_log("ITEMDESC: {$ITEMDESC}");
error_log("ITEMDESC2: {$ITEMDESC2}");
error_log("SQL: {$SQL}");
?>
```

apache2 error log contains:

> ITEMDESC: This is Bob's Text
>   ITEMDESC2: This is Bob\\'s Text
>   SQL: insert into table (description) values ('This is Bob\\'s Text');

browser output (on-screen):

> ITEMDESC: This is Bob's Text
>   ITEMDESC2: This is Bob\'s Text
>   SQL: insert into table (description) values ('This is Bob\'s Text');

Comment: Sounds like your PHP is set to have magic_quotes enabled (evil pile of dren). So its escaping the escaping.

Comment: Any reason you're using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead of a prepared statement with parameter binding?

Comment: I checked for magic quotes, and they do not appear to exist in this version. I confirmed this at php.net before posting as well.
"This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0."
http://us2.php.net/magic_quotes

Comment: It's good to have all that info but please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Well, even if its been removed, it can still be turned on, as we have an older 5.5 server where it is clearly ON. But anyhoo... you should be using prepared statements anyways.

Comment: @Randall I'm highly dubious of that claim. Care to provide some working samples?

Comment: @philipxy I will try to find a site that provides mysqli connections.

Comment: Even if you give all necessary code without a site we can see how and where you are actually calling what & answerers with sites can execute. Also you could report what you get from echoing string variables before & after use, which should be part of your own debugging. PS Read about SO stack snippets.

Comment: @philipxy are you reading the same question? OP clearly has examples of the values before and after using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Ok, so obviously the issue is with `error_log` and not `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @Phil I might agree, but when inserting that "escaped" variable into a table field, the contents are truncated at the "escaped" quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should migrate your code to [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) instead. That would let you avoid this strange issue and also provide better security.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'INSERT INTO FooBar(description) VALUES (?)');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['ITEMDESC']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Though, I personally perfer using [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), because it had the option to have named parameters, that make the SQL a lot more readable and the interface is PSR-2 comaptible.